# My Custom CSS radio buttons are not being recognised in my javascript

Tags: javascript, css, radio-button

I used an online javascript writer to create my javascript for a personality quiz as part of a project at work, originally I had my radio buttons as the default, and the javascript worked. Each radio button has a value between 1 and 10 which corresponds to a pre-determined personality type.

However I changed the radio buttons to be more accessible to users via css and to look better, and as such the javascript isn't working. Hopefully someone can figure out a solution to this? When I run the Error Console on safari, it states that it can't find the variable : finish, which is the action on the form.

Custom CSS for Radio buttons:

```
li{
  color: white;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 75%;
  height: 25px;
 border-bottom: 0px solid white;
}
li input[type=radio]{
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
}

li label{
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 25px 0px 25px 60px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  height: 30px;
  z-index: 9;
  cursor: default;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s linear;
}

li:hover label{
 color: #ffd061;
}

li .check{
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border: 5px solid white;
  border-radius: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  top: 30px;
  left: 20px;
 z-index: 5;
 transition: border .25s linear;
 -webkit-transition: border .25s linear;
}

li:hover .check {
  border: 5px solid #ffd061;
}

li .check::before {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
 content: '';
  border-radius: 100%;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  top: 5px;
 left: 5px;
  margin: auto;
 transition: background 0.25s linear;
 -webkit-transition: background 0.25s linear;
}

input[type=radio]:checked ~ .check {
  border: 5px solid #ffd061;
}

input[type=radio]:checked ~ .check::before{
  background: #ffd061;
}


input[type=radio]:checked ~ label{
  color: #ffd061;
}
```

Javascript

```
<script>
function finish() {
var results = new Array("none","Part-Of-The-AU","Fresher","Edgy-Anthro-Student","Postgraduate","WannaBNOC","Corporate-Student","General-Course","Rich-Kids","Left-Wing-Social-Activist","Library-Queen");
 var nums = new Array(11);
 for(var i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) nums[i] = 0;
 for(var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
  var q = javascript:void(0)document.forms['quiz'].elements['question_'+i];
  if(q[0].type=='checkbox') {
   var n = 0;
  }
  for(var j = 0; j < q.length; j++) {
   if(q[j].checked) {
    var a = q[j].value.split(',');
    for(var k = 0; k < a.length; k++) {
     nums[a[k]]++;
    }
    if(q[j].type=='radio') break;
    else n++;
   }
   if(j == q.length-1&&q[j].type=='radio') {nums[0]++;}
  }
  if(q[0].type=='checkbox'&&((document.forms['quiz'].elements['question_'+i+'_min']&&n<document.forms['quiz'].elements['question_'+i+'_min'].value)||(document.forms['quiz'].elements['question_'+i+'_max']&&n>document.forms['quiz'].elements['question_'+i+'_max'].value))) nums[0]++;
 }
 var j = new Array('0');
 for (i in nums) if(nums[i]>nums[j[0]]){j=new Array(''+i);} else if(nums[i]==nums[j[0]])j[j.length] = i;
 //var o = '';for(var i in results)o+=results[i]+'='+nums[i]+'\n';
 //alert(o);
 if(nums[0]!=0) {
  alert('You missed or incorrectly answered '+nums[0]+' questions!');
 }
 else if(j[0]==0) {
  alert('No result could be determined.');
 }
 else {
  location (results[j[0]]);
 }
}

</script>
```

New way in which the radio buttons are styled in the form :

```
<ul><li>
<input name="question_1" type="radio" value="10" id="j-option" >
    <label for="j-option">Library Vending Machines</label>
    <span class="check"> </span>
</ul></li>
```

Original way in which they were styled:

```
 <input name="question_1" type="radio" value="10" >Library Vending Machines
```

Start of the form :

```
<form name="quiz" action="javascript:finish();">
```

Hopefully someone has a solution to this. Cheers

Comment: In your new Html, you are closing the <li> outside the <ul>

Comment: Hi, thanks although this does not solve the issue with the radio buttons not being working with the javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to be this line “var q = javascript:void(0)document.forms['quiz'].elements['question_'+i];”, but I cannot tell what it should have been.

Comment: I worked it out, the Javascript:void(0) is breaking it, so thank you!